# Display UL List Horizontally

Tags: css, list

I am trying to make my subnav list display horizontally rather than stacked. I have tried a few different things, but I cant figure it out. I have tried to use Float, but it messes with the width of the divs below it. Not sure why this happens.

Can anyone help me?

http://jsfiddle.net/9bued/1/

Comment: What do you mean that floating the subnav list items left "messes" with the width of the divs below the list? Looked fine to me when I floated them (Update: provided you give the div below the list a clear: both).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete the width limitation as Habib suggested, then add a clearfix class to the containing ul.

```
.clearfix:after { content: "."; display: block; height: 0; clear: both; visibility: hidden; }
.clearfix { display: inline-block; }

/* Hides from IE-mac \*/ 
* html .clearfix { height: 1%; }
.clearfix { display: block; }
/* End hide from IE-mac */
```

The styles for the clearfix should always go at the bottom of your style block or style sheet.

Comment: I must be doing something wrong. I can get this to work. What do you think?http://jsfiddle.net/nategines/9bued/8/

Comment: The bars at the bottom are not displaying as they should. I need them to be displayed like this http://jsfiddle.net/9bued/1/ (first example)

Comment: In this one http://jsfiddle.net/nategines/9bued/9/ you have every child li of #subtabs set to float right, thus those li's are also floating right. Change that style to say #subnav li and it looks correct.

Answer (score 1):

Delete the width limitation (`width: 10em;`) in `#navwidth`

Comment: I tried that, but it changes the shape of the colored divs below it. How would I get around this?

Answer (score 0):

just add to your CSS : display: inline-block;